# ROS autostart with daemontools

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello community,

I'd like to start ros directly after ubuntu system start...
Is anybody using daemontools ?

http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/faq/create.html#why

Cheers
Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11753/ros-autostart-with-daemontools/) by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2011-11-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if you're only looking to use daemontools, but [here](http://pastebin.com/7wsUKbd1) is what I use to start ROS automatically. I've commented the code to explain what I'm doing.

Copy this script to /etc/init.d and then execute the following command:

```
sudo update-rc.d script-name defaults 99
```

ROS will now boot on startup into a seperate screen. The only catch is that it boots as the root user. Thus, to access it, you must use the command:

```
sudo screen -r
```

and it will bring you to the terminal containing the ROS graph.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2013-01-11**:
I tried your script but it didn't work for me. The source path is definitely right but the output of the console when booting is
/etc/rc2.d/S99panda_cam_startup: 45: source: not found
Found
/etc/rc2.d/S99panda_cam_startup: 45: bc: not found
/etc/rc2.d/S99panda_cam_startup: 45: screen: not found